# I always jumb into an error while trying expo-cli on my windows 7 32bits terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, expo

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.13.1 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules@expo\traveling-fastlane-darwin):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.13.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...__joi-15.0.0.tgz","

fi'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\IBDAC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-08T01_09_04_839Z-debug.log